# Convert c# console output to Textbox output

Tags: c#, wpf, console

I'm very new in CSharp and I know you found this question very stupid, I need  an idea how to convert the output from console to textbox. thanks

```
foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);
    Console.WriteLine("  Drive type: {0}", d.DriveType);
    if (d.IsReady == true)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel);
        Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat);
        Console.WriteLine(
           "  Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes",
           d.AvailableFreeSpace);

        Console.WriteLine(
           "  Total available space:          {0, 15} bytes",
           d.TotalFreeSpace);

        Console.WriteLine(
           "  Total size of drive:            {0, 15} bytes ",
           d.TotalSize);
    }
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Comment: I saw WPF tag here. So, did you mean WPF textbox?

Comment: this is only simple use of `DriveInfo` and no value to convert to any other platform

Comment: You probably want to consider searching key phrases like "convert console to WPF" on this forum. Like this: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=convert+console+to+wpf

Answer (score 2):

Console.WriteLine is calls a WriteLine on an internal `StreamWriter` whose stream is the Console.Output.

What you can do is use another object, like a `StringBuilder` and write your results to the StringBuilder and then set the `Text` from the string result of `StringBuilder.ToString()`

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendFormat("Drive {0}\n", d.Name);
sb.AppendFormat("  Drive type: {0}\n", d.DriveType);
    if (d.IsReady == true)


    {
        sb.AppendFormat("  Volume label: {0}\n", d.VolumeLabel);
        sb.AppendFormat("  File system: {0}\n", d.DriveFormat);
        sb.AppendFormat(
            "  Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes\n",
            d.AvailableFreeSpace);

         sb.AppendFormat(
            "  Total available space:          {0, 15} bytes\n",
            d.TotalFreeSpace);

         sb.AppendFormat(
            "  Total size of drive:            {0, 15} bytes \n",
            d.TotalSize);
    }
txtBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Alternately in your loop, you can just add new lines of text to your `TextBox`

```
    txtBox.Text += String.Format(("Drive {0}\n", d.Name);
    txtBox.Text += String.Format(("  Drive type: {0}\n", d.DriveType);
    if (d.IsReady == true)


    {
        txtBox.Text += String.Format(("  Volume label: {0}\n", d.VolumeLabel);
        txtBox.Text += String.Format(("  File system: {0}\n", d.DriveFormat);
        txtBox.Text += String.Format((
            "  Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes\n",
            d.AvailableFreeSpace);

        txtBox.Text +=String.Format((
            "  Total available space:          {0, 15} bytes\n",
            d.TotalFreeSpace);

        txtBox.Text +=String.Format((
            "  Total size of drive:            {0, 15} bytes \n",
            d.TotalSize);
    }
```